# CSS design for large form - Design Advice

Tags: forms, html, css

I have a large form that consists of all the input (text, checkbox, radio, etc...), I have them grouped together in a fieldset tag and a legend for each feildset. Each input has a label associated with it as well. My question is what is the best approach to display the information on one screen and take advantage of the horizontal real estate the user might or might not have?

I would love it to be all CSS with minimal (if any) table layout(s) as I think tables are for tablature data and not presentation. CSS3 and HTML5 are welcome as well.

Also I would like to have the ability to add branding as this might need to look like another site instead of the original site developed for.

What would be the best approach for this? I have the idea I would use li tags to do the horizontal look but I would like to break to the next line at the end of the screen (Think no scrolling horizontal but vertical is okay)

CSS Novice looking for design pattern advice

This is an example but I think I have around 50 fields

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Large Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="">

<fieldset>
<legend>***</legend> 

<label for="fname">First Name</label><br />
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="" /><br /><br />

<label for="lname">Last Name</label><br />
<input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" value="" /><br /><br />

<label for="gender">Gender</label><br />
<select name="gender" id="gender">
    <option value="">-- select</option>
    <option value="male">Male</option>
    <option value="female">Female</option>
</select>

</fieldset>

<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is that you want to remove the `<br/>` tags from the form. If you need vertical space, use CSS padding and margins since they're easier to change and make spacing consistent.

With that out of the way, other than branding (which will influence the look and feel of the form the most) the things you want to consider the most are accessibility and ease of use. Your use of labels and unwillingness to use tables for layout are a good start for accessibility so I'm not going to mention it further.

For ease of use, you'll need to make sure that each field can be tabbed to (in an order that makes sense), has a clear, meaningful label, has no unnecessary validation rules (such as forbidding whitespace in a phone number - don't force the user to clean data that can be cleaned automatically) and those validation rules that are necessary have clear, easy to understand messages that appear, ideally, as the user is entering the data rather than waiting for the user to submit the form.

Each of your field sets should be visually grouped either by colour, with a border or some other method. Individual field set should not be broken up, but different field sets can be separate from each other as long as they are contextually different (like address versus interests, for example).

Since you're already grouping field sets, you can use them as your basic unit of page layout. Each set could be floated, for example, in order to maximimize horizontal usage regardless of the user's browser width. As long as the sets are visually distinct enough and are clearly labelled there shouldn't really be any issues with that.

If consistency is more your thing, then each field set should be separated from each other vertically. That would make sure the form is ordered and laid out the same way for every user. Again, the important thing is visual consistency and ease of use. Users are used to forms being laid out vertically so the wasted horizontal space of doing it that way shouldn't be a very big concern.

Just remember: you're making something that should be easy to use and not frustrating. The position of fields should reflect that: they should be natural, grouping like fields together and separating groups of like fields from dissimilar fields. As long as you're keeping that in mind you're probably in good shape.

And don't forget to do some quick usability tests to make sure your validations make sense and are clear.

Comment: Wow some great points, big thanks!!! I never thought to use the field sets like that. So if I understand you correctly, group all related fields together in a field set vertically but group the field sets horizontally? Also the tab order is something I always seem to over look. Again great tips and thanks!!!

Comment: @Phill: I'm not really recommending a specific layout style, since that is usually covered by the branding of what you're trying to create. If the brand style dictates that you should not waste horizontal space, then you'll probably want to go with the grid layout that Frédéric Hamidi suggested (assuming you're OK with CSS3). If you want a lower-tech solution, I'd go with floating field sets or a simple vertical layout.

Comment: I'm interested in the Floating Field Set implementation, are there any good examples of this? Would I wrap them into a div or ul? not to savey with CSS yet but I thought this would be a great learning exercise for me. Thanks

Comment: @Phill: There is no difference between floating fields and floating any other block element, so finding any resource on CSS floating should get you started. But with respect to field sets, it's unlikely that each one will have the same height (unless you force them to have the same height), so it will be difficult to achieve a layout that doesn't have ragged bottoms (again, unless you force them to have the same height). If you're forcing things to have the same height, what you're really doing is building a grid-like layout, which is why I suggest going with Frédéric Hamidi's grids instead.

Comment: yes I agree they are similar to the grid part but having the floating aspect to adjust to screen resolution would be different. I understand the visual layouts will have to be the same height to look consistent and that is acceptable to me.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [CSS3 grid positioning](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid/#examples). It has a clear but powerful syntax, e.g. from the link:

```
body {
    grid-columns: * * (0.5in * *)[2];
    grid-rows: 20% *;
    columns: 3;
    column-gap: 0.5in;
}
```

Elements use `gr` units to choose their grid cell:

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 2gr;
    width: 3gr;
}
```

You would only have to give an `id` to your `fieldset`s then set their position and extents in your style file.

Comment: I have heard of grid layouts done in CSS but have never seen (well looked at the code) of one. My question would be, "Would the grid change by screen resolution"? So if a user had a 800x600 screen and I have a 4 grid layout, would they layout stay the same as 4 grids going across or would it be flexible enough to stack 2 grids over 2 grids?

Comment: The grid model remains static and is subject to `overflow` like other block elements. If you define a 4x1 grid, it will remain 4x1 when the user resizes his window, either reducing cell width or showing a scrollbar depending on whether you used relative or absolute units in the grid definition.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It looks great but I would like to implement a dynamic grid layout if possible as the end user(s) have large to small screens and I think it's annoying on a smaller screen to scroll left or right to view the entire page. Scrolling vertically (in my opinion) just seems to flow better. Thanks for the fast reply and idea of grid layouts, let me know if you find a more flexible solution

Answer (score 2):

One of my favorite ways to group large forms is with the jQuery style accordion. It allows you to abstract the form into key groupings, keep the form all on one page, and eliminate the need for page scrolling; all with an intuitive user interface.

A good example of this is the [Barnes & Noble](http://www.bn.com) checkout form process.

Comment: I do love jQuery but wanted to keep it as much CSS as possible and minimal (if any) JavaScript. I have implemented something like this in jQuery: http://jsbin.com/ezesi Stack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126489/jquery-examples-horizontal-accordion-table-instead-of-un-ordered-lists-upda

Answer (score 2):

Check out [CSS Flexbox](http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/flexbox/quick/) for some liquid flexibility withing you design sets. I would also recommend picking a "style" and sticking with it. Agree with Welbog.

Comment: Looks great for newer browsers and +1 for HTML5

Answer (score 1):

I guess that if you have a form with 50 fields, you surely have to split it to themed **tabs**. Say 3 to 5 tabs. They can be implemented by Javascript.

You may want to save input data on-the-fly, because the user may need a long time to finish the form, so there is bigger possibility that he will catch a loss of internet connection or some other factor, that will erase his half-finished form, which would probably dissapoint him and leave your site.

Also consider that user has to have a place for his eye to rest, so be sure to make enough blank room between inputs.

Comment: I would recommend tabs only if Ajaxy validation messages are infeasible for whatever reason. The benefit of tabs is that they permit more frequent submission, which leads to earlier validation and saving, but at the cost of hiding the information the user has already entered. Use tabs only if you can guarantee that users won't need to look to previous fields to change them or to double check them (or provide that functionality to them explicitly). Tabs are also useful if some groups of fields are optional depending on the values of other fields (like a flow with optional tabs).

Comment: I thought about doing tabs but the constraints/requirements of the project limit my ability to do so. It's for internal uses so it doesn't need to look the best but since I have some flexibility on the design aspect I thought it would be a great exercise for me to hone my skills and learn. Thanks for the tip